Open Graph Embeds dont work over traefik proxy
Ive been trying to fully migrate my personal website to use traefik, instead of just forwarding the ports directly so i can have subdomains,for some reason discord and tumblr; tumblr error ss
just cant embed it and the discord embed debugger, discord embed debugger ss just says "Internal Error" I've waited a few days and it still doesn't work unless I just don't run my website through traefik but i want to be able to run multiple websites at different subdomains on the same machine so that's just not viable for me
Stuff ive tried;

It loads fine in the browser
https works fine it even will automatically attempt to use https instead of http
http works fine if you cant upgrade to https
getting rid of traefik and this does work but i need some way to proxy based off of subdomain that i can configure in my compose files lest i go insane
When you curl it provides the exact same information it used to curl ss
Looking through Wireshark nothing looks out of the ordinary
It even loads on my phone and school Chromebook on their network

What i would expect is for it to just load without issue given that curl provides identical information diff checker ss (the css files names changed because i recompiled the site for the 4th time while sanity checking myself)

I fixed it.
So my issue was I had a misconfigured full chain cert (seemingly ran the command to merge my certs twice) but like my chromebook didn't care and firefox didn't care and curl doesn't even check your certs.
I've corrected this and now it works perfectly.
